# Modifying a list from 2 lists side by side

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have typed the following code for printing 2 lists side by side

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['4', '7', '3']

print("options  votes")
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i] + '\t ' + b[i])
```

In the 1st list, I want to enter numbers ranging from 1-20. How can I do so without actually typing each number from 1 to 20

Comment: `list(range(1, 21))` ? Also, your title doesn't match with your question. What are you actually asking?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to type 2. I wrote 3 by mistake

Comment: You can take a look at [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) for equally length list and [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) (use `from itertools import zip_longest`) for unequal length lists.

Comment: You can edit it but it still doesn't match with the question in your post. In title, you are asking how to print side by side and in the post you are asking how to create a list that consists of numbers ranging form 1 to 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to enter same range of numbers because you used **range(len(a))** in your for loop so they have to have same range of numbers:

```
a = [x for x in range(1, 21)]
b = [c for c in range(1, 21)]

print("options  votes")
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(f"{a[i]} \t  {b[i]}")
```

**OR**

```
a = range(1, 21)
b = range(1, 21)
a_list = list(a)
b_list = list(b)

print("options  votes")
for i in range(len(a_list)):
    print(f"{a_list[i]} \t  {b_list[i]}")
```